# Como oculto mensajes de la terminal

Tags: bash

Creé un código que  reemplaza un directorio al actualizarse pero da un mensaje de error:

> Please try again:  mkdir: no se puede crear el directorio «hola_asm»:
>   El archivo ya existe mkdir: no se puede crear el directorio
>   «/home/fyxov/Documentos/ASM»: El archivo ya existe

¿Cómo hago para que la terminal no muestre esa info? El programa funciona
pero, no me gusta que escriba eso al final

Comment: con solo agregar  -p al mkdir un ejemplo :`mkdir -p carpeta_existe` tienes

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres una respuesta que se aplique únicamente al comando mkdir, simplemente
añade la bandera -p para no mostrar errores cuando la carpeta existe.

Por otro lado, si quieres una respuesta que se aplique de manera general para
ocultar mensajes de error, puedes hacer uso de la redirección de flujos, cuya
sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
[comando] [descriptor]>[archivo_al_que_redirigir]
```

[descriptor] es un número que representa un flujo de datos. Todo proceso en unix
tiene al menos tres descriptores:

- 0   Entrada estándar
- 1   Salida estándar
- 2   Salida de error estándar

Por lo que puedes hacer, por ejemplo:

```
mkdir carpeta 2> archivo_errores.txt
```

Para ejecutar el comando mkdir y, si este emite mensajes de error, no mostrarlos
en la consola sino que mandarlos al archivo llamado archivo_errores.txt (El cual
se crea si no existe).

Sin embargo es muy probable que no quieras conservar la salida ni siquiera en un
archivo. Para tal fin existe el archivo especial /dev/null, también conocido
como periférico nulo, el cual descarta toda la información que se le envía. Ya
entrados en esto, podrías redireccionar también los contenidos de salida
estándar para que un comando no emita ningún mensaje de la siguiente forma:

```
mkdir carpeta 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Lo cual se puede abreviar como:

```
mkdir carpeta 2&>1 > /dev/null
```

Donde "2&>1" significa "asocia el descriptor 2 (salida estándar) con el
descriptor 1 (salida de error estándar)".